# Regarding keeping the date information only after using pd.to_datetime

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, datetime

The original record has the following format, i.e., the date information is stored in the string format

```
records[‘start_date’].unique()
array([nan, '6/3/2012', '10/20/2013'], dtype=object)
```

As suggested by this forum, I used the following code to transfer it to datetime

```
Records[‘start_date’] = pd.to_datatime(records[‘start_date’], format =’%m/%d/%Y’)
```

The transferred array has the following summary

```
array(['NaT', '2012-06-03T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2013-10-20T00:00:00.000000000',], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

I would like to make the transferred date time format more lean, and keep the date only without keeping those minutes/seconds information. In specific, I would like the format like this

```
array(['NaT', '2012-06-03,
       '2013-10-20',], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

How to achieve that goal? Thanks

Comment: Just don't give it the `format`. The way the string is, the `month` is the first one, thus the function `pd.to_datetime(record['start_date'])` would do what you need. or rather pd.Series(your_array). Althoug this still keeps you array the same

Comment: @Onyambu, That's not going to change the behaviour OP is seeing, e.g. the datetime will still "show up" as `'2012-06-03T00:00:00.000000000'`.

Comment: @jpp, Sure the array will remain the same. On the other hand, yours will change the class of the object from a datetime to sting. Of which OP doesn't want that

Comment: @Onyambu, Not with my second alternative :). Point is it's not possible to have what OP wants. Because it's just a display/representation issue. `np.datetime64` is stored as integers (`int64` to be precise). You just trigger some extra logic when you use `print`.

Comment: @The second alternative stores them as object I believe, the array will be different from the array given by OP still. so I still believe we all compromised. The underlying structure is different from what OP needs, yet we both get the results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to make the transferred date time format more lean, and
>   keep the date only without keeping those minutes/seconds information.

This is not accurate. `np.datetime64` is essentially a thin wrapper on `int64`. As such, this format will store dates (including time, etc) *more* efficiently than a string. Don't be fooled by the display: `'2012-06-03T00:00:00.000000000'` is just a *text representation* of an underlying integer. Here's some evidence:

```
import datetime, sys, numpy as np

now = datetime.datetime.now()

x_date = sys.getsizeof(np.datetime64(now))             # 40
x_int = sys.getsizeof(np.datetime64(now).astype(int))  # 28 
y = sys.getsizeof('10/20/2013')                        # 59
```

Now, if you are concerned primarily with *display*, then you can in Pandas convert your series to strings held in an `object` dtype series:

```
records['start_date'] = records['start_date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

An alternative is to use a series of `datetime.date` objects:

```
records['start_date'] = records['start_date'].dt.date
```

Just note that further manipulations will be memory and performance inefficient, more so with the first option.